# How to do an inline string replace in Javascrip?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a real estate LeafLet map using a json URL to display markers with popups.  The popups have an address and photo coming in from the json url.

Some results do not have photos.  Because of this my map will not load and I'm receiving an error in console:
**Uncaught TypeError: element.Media is null**

I'd like to create an if statement that replaces the null images with an Image Not Found link.  I can not figure out how to do the if statement in my const arrayOfMarkers function...any advice?

```
const arrayOfMarkers = results.value.map(element => L.marker([element.Latitude,
element.Longitude]).bindPopup('<a href="property.php?id='+element.ListingId+'"
  ><div class="card">
    <img
      src="'+ element.Media[0].MediaURL+"
      class="card-img-top"
      style="height: 160px; max-height: 160px; object-fit: scale-down"
    />
    <div class="d-inline-flex p-2 justify-content-between align-items-start">
      <div class="rp-1 bd-highlight">
        '+element.StreetNumber + " " + element.StreetName+" " +
        element.StreetSuffix+ "<br />" +element.City+',
        '+element.StateOrProvince+' '+element.PostalCode+'
      </div>
      <div class="lp-1 bd-highlight" style="text-align: right">
        '+numberFormatter.format(element.ListPrice)+ " <br />
        ID " + element.ListingId+'
      </div>
    </div>
  </div></a
>'));
```

UPDATE:
I have implemented Fred's suggestion below and only included the image information to make it easier to read.  With this change images do not appear anymore and the error of null is still showing up in the console.  Have I entered it incorrectly?:

```
var imageNotFoundURL = "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.kgfkdioyvqIrLPdA5bXckAHaE8%26pid%3DApi&f=1";

var arrayOfMarkers = results.value.map(element => L.marker(
    [element.Latitude, element.Longitude
  ]).bindPopup(
  '<a href="property.php?id='+element.ListingId+'"><div class="card"><img src="'+ (element.Media && element.Media[0] && element.Media[0].MediaURL) || imageNotFoundURL +'"></a>'));

const mcg = L.markerClusterGroup();
mcg.addLayers(arrayOfMarkers);
mcg.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to not render any elements without `element.Media` defined. This code is completely unreadable, so can you please format it better?

Comment: yes, please do.

Comment: Do you really need to do this in a single line? Handling nulls and altering the HTML string will be a lot easier for you if you format the code.

Comment: The edit's much nicer to read, but is now invalid JS

Comment: @FredStark  yeah, I'll leave it up to Joey to edit his own question now,

Comment: lol...I am not very familiar with JavaScript but the code that has been replaced (that looks better than my concatenation) breaks the page and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

First off, as others have said, you're going to have a much better time if you split this out so it's not on one line.

> I'd like to create an if statement that replaces the null images with an Image Not Found link. I can not figure out how to do the if statement in my const arrayOfMarkers function...any advice?

So the key spot for this is where the `img`'s `src` is set:

```
'<img src="' + element.Media[0].MediaURL + '"'
```

As you've discovered, this fails if there's no Media, so you need to check if Media exists and fallback to the not found link:

```
'<img src="'+ (element.Media && element.Media[0] && element.Media[0].MediaURL) || imageNotFoundURL + '"'
```

Or if you are using babel or don't need to support old browsers:

```
'<img src="'+ element.Media?.[0]?.MediaURL || imageNotFoundURL + '"'
```

Of course, you'll also need to define `imageNotFoundURL` somewhere above this code

Comment: Tried to use but having issues. Popups are now blank.
 
const arrayOfMarkers = results.value.map(element => L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude]).bindPopup('<a href="property.php?id="+element.ListingId+""><div class="card"><img src="'+ element.Media?.[0]?.MediaURL || imageNotFoundURL + '">r...etc`

Comment: did you set `imageNotFoundURL` to a url?

Comment: Yes I added this directly above: `var imageNotFoundURL = "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.kgfkdioyvqIrLPdA5bXckAHaE8%26pid%3DApi&f=1";`